# Show custom entity table field on admin form

Tags: admin-panel, shipping-address, magento2.3.4

I added custom field "address_type" to "custom_address_entity" (not attribute) table and now I need to add this field on create new address from ADMIN form on create new order. Where and what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

I have created a customer address attribute to showing on adminhtml checkout form.

> **File**:- VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php 

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "address_type");

         $attributesInfo = [
            'address_type' => [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'static',
                'label' => 'Address Type',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'position' => 100,
                'used_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_in_grid' => true,
                'searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'system' => 0,
            ],
        ];


        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }

        $vatIdAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'address_type');
        $vatIdAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'checkout_register',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'adminhtml_customer_address', 
            'customer_address_edit', 
            'customer_register_address'
            ]
        );
        $vatIdAttribute->setData('is_used_in_grid', true);
        $vatIdAttribute->setData('is_visible_in_grid', true);
        $vatIdAttribute->setData('is_filterable_in_grid', true);
        $vatIdAttribute->save();
        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}

?>
```

If already create customer address attribute using InstallData script then you use UpgradeData

> **File**:-VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Nuucleon\Customerattributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory 
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory 
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var array 
     */
    public $customer_attribute_used_in_forms = ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','customer_account_create','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory 
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;


    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     * @param QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();


            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'address_type', [
                'type' => 'static',
                'label' => 'Address Type',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                null,
                'address_type');

            $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'address_type')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_checkout']
                ])->save();;

        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> **Output**:-
>   [image]

Comment: it shows on form when I add attribute but how do I show when field is on entity table